# Does ImageNet dataset contains watermarked images?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, imagenet

I am currently working on a project for watermark detection using Deep Learning.
Can anyone tell if Image Net Data-set contains watermarked images?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ImageNet images do have watermarks. The most common one I have encountered is the iStockphoto watermark. An example image with this watermark is shown
[below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKozA.jpg). Its ImageNet path is train/n02356798/n02356798_177.JPEG. There are other watermarks in the dataset as well.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, Imagenet consists of images collected from different parts of the web. Images are organised into categories (classes) and labelled. In the past, I looked at the images visually and don't remember seeing any watermarks. You can visually inspect the classes and images you're interested to double check on the imagenet website.